# How do multiple return statements work in C?

Tags: c

I was under the impression that any function in C would support only one return statement until I came across a few notes where there was a mention of multiple return statements. How do these multiple return statements work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `return` statement that is executed will terminate the function and its value will be used.

However, there can obviously be multiple execution paths - and they can return different values. Actually in a non-void function every possible execution path **has** to return something. The easiest way to achieve this is obviously having a `return` statement at the very end of the function.

```
if(foo)
    return 23;
else
    return 42;
```

There are [some arguments](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleFunctionExitPoint) for having just a single return statement in your code; consider reading the article if any of them apply to you. A good example is code that always needs to do some clean-up. In this case you will only want to return after this has been done - so you'll set a variable for the return value and use `goto` to jump to the cleanup-and-return section at the end of the function if you need to return early.

Comment: I believe that the `else` is redundant :)

Answer (score 1):

well the first return statement it'll come across will stop further execution and return control to caller function. if you want to access multiple values after processing in a function then you can use struct or arrays these objects you can return frm the function and thus you will get the updated values as whole struct/array object

Comment: can you please eloborate for more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: well you can visit <a href="http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/">here</a> for more info. send a return a struct type object then you can get all the values changed by you in your function

Answer (score 0):

Whichever return is hit first will cause the function to exit and control to be handed back to the caller.

For example:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

In this case, if `x` is `0`, then the first return will be hit and `0` will be returned. If any other number is passed, the second return is hit and `1` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
int function(int input)
{
   if (input == 1) return 1;
   else return 0;
}
```

Well, they work as return statements. Of course it only make sense to have one return statement for each code path in your function.

Answer (score 0):

If there are returns in other logic blocks.. then you could conceivably have multiple returns in a function.

but something like:
    return 1;
    return 2;

not so much.

Answer (score -1):

The rule is that for a non void fonction it must be impossible to reach the end of the function without encontering a return statement.

When executing a fonction, when you hit a return statement you exit the function no matter where you are in the function (inside a for or a if …). So if there are two return statements in the same branch, only the first one will be taken into account.