# Series/parallel function

Tags: c, function

I don't know how to get two variables from a function, this is my noob attempt, is this possible and if so how is it done?

```
#include <stdio.h>
float seriesParallel (float r1, float r2);// function prototype
int main()
{
    float r1,r2,series,parallel;
    printf("Enters two numbers: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&r1,&r2);
    seriesParallel = seriesParallel(r1, r2);// function call
    printf("series = %f and parallel = %f", series, parallel);
    return 0;
}
float seriesParallel (float r1, float r2)// function definition
{
    float series, parallel;
    series = (r1 + r2);
    parallel = (r1 * r2) / (r1 +r2);
    return series;
    return parallel;

}
```

Comment: You might want to use a pointer here -- you'll pass the two inputs as well as two locations to the function. The function will write the two outputs to those location, where main can then find them. Depending on where you are with your learning process you might need to read a bit further to make this happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do multiple return statements work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681857/how-do-multiple-return-statements-work)

Comment: @Sneftel It is not a duplicate of that, this is about returning several values, not several `return` statements.

Comment: @Acorn Yes, exactly. The author of the linked question had the same misconception as the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Return a `struct` of two values.

  ```
  struct Values { float series, parallel; }

  struct Values seriesParallel (float r1, float r2)
  {
      struct Values ret;
      ret.series = (r1 + r2);
      ret.parallel = (r1 * r2) / (r1 +r2);
      return ret;
  }
  ```
- Return some of the values through a pointer.

  ```
  void seriesParallel (float r1, float r2, float* series, float* parallel)
  {
      *series = (r1 + r2);
      *parallel = (r1 * r2) / (r1 +r2);
  }
  ```

Comment: I used your suggestion of pointers because that makes the most sense but I'm unable to actually get that to work in my main function, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @Nationz You need to call it like `seriesParallel(r1, r2, &series, &parallel);`. Hope that helps!